# How to integrate Facebook in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios4, ipad

I am working one of the application in which i have to implement facebook through FBConnect, i have done with that and it is working ,can post to the userwall, however the only thing which i didn't get is how to like any status updated by the user by default.Suppose in the appliction if user login and post anything through fbconnect that status should be automatically liked by default, i have search a lot however didn't find any solution.Please help me regarding for that

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do it in a single go. But you can get the POST_ID of the post you've just posted and then send HTTP POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes` to achieve what you want.